# How did Elly drown?

Tags: ending, about-elly

In the Iranian film *About Elly* (2009), Elly was seen to be flying a kite.. In the next moment, she was gone.. Near the end of the movie, it is revealed that she actually drowned.. but how did she drown? in an attempt to save that kid?

Why did her mother say she didn't know about any trip? We saw that Elly phoned her the previous day (though we don't know who she was actually talking to) .. 
Why did her fiance lie about his identity?

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_Elly

Answer (score 1):

When the kids are playing in the beach, Nazi asks Elly to be in charge of the children. So we assume she felt responsible about the kid Arash when she found out he went into the water after flying that kite and went in the water for him.
Elly was actually talking to her mother the day before but she told her mother not to tell anyone about her being on the trip. On the other hand, it is culturally not accepted for her mother to let her go on a trip without her legal fiance being informed. That's why her mother didn't reveal that she knew she was on a trip.
What her fiance did on the phone actually looks a bit natural to me. a stranger called him on Elly's phone and didn't even introduce himself and asked who he was. The fiance didn't have to answer anything when someone was calling him with Elly's phone and didn't say anything.
The whole reality about Elly is that Elly told her friend(Sepideh) about her fiance but kept her fiance a secret from others, also kept her trip and the fact that she was going to meet another guy from her family.

Answer (score 1):

I think you guys are missing something. ٍElly told her new friends that her mother has a weak heart. but when they called her mother they didn't notice anything except being very cold to them and they have let it be on that they have called her mom so many times! She probably got drowned, or maybe she... I can't think of anything but drowned, but I also find it very weird that the fiance was looking 
 at Elly's bag very mysteriously at the end! you remember last time we saw Elly? what was she thinking about? she wasn't looking at the sea. she hasn't noticed that the baby is gone. what did she actually do?

Answer (score 0):

at first
When she jumped into the sea to save the child, she wears clothes. it makes her to heavy to swim. There was kinda stone beach around. that makes strong water flow. There was not a good place  to swim. These two are enough to make someone drowns.

for the second 
on her phone call when she was in the car, she was **completely alone** and there is no reason to lie. In this conversation to her mom, she asked her mom to tell no one that she is in a travel. After that, her fiance called her and she didn't answer and keep her mind to his conversation with Ahmad.

for extra knowledge
Right at this moment, Ahmad says: the bitter ending is better than a endless bitter.